# Format part of a column into Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:**

How can i extract and format the last 14 digits as a `DATETIME` type value?

**Situation:**

I have an `id` column that contains several different characters and the last 14 characters represent `DATETIME`.

**Example:**

```
abcdefghj02002216112014
```

**Key:**

The 14 digits are: `second`, `minute`, `hour`, `day`, `month`, `year`

**Query:**

```
SELECT RIGHT(id,15)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with SUBSTRING functions

> This function returns a datetime value for the specified date and time arguments.

as next:-

```
create table #MyTable (id nvarchar(100))
insert #MyTable values ('abcdefghj02002216112014')

select DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(id,14),11,15) /*year*/, 
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(id,14),9,2) /*month*/,  
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(id,14),7,2) /*day*/, 
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(id,14),5,2) /*hour*/,
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(id,14),3,2) /* minute*/, 
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(id,14),0,3) /*seconds*/,
                    00 /*milliseconds*/)
                    from  #MyTable

drop table #MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
declare @variable varchar(50)='abcdefghj02002216112014'
declare @T bigint=RIGHT(@variable, 14)

SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( @T % 10000, 
                          (@T / 10000) % 100, 
                          (@T / 1000000) % 100, 
                          (@T / 100000000) % 100, 
                          (@T / 10000000000) % 100, 
                          (@T / 1000000000000) % 100, 0 ) AS Result;
```

**Result:**

16/11/2014 22:00:02

**DATETIMEFROMPARTS:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: if you can  add date conversion as well, I will be happy to up-vote this answer

Comment: But again you didn't convert result to Date type. Please convert your output to DATE.

Comment: what is the purpose of @@version?

Comment: Ah. It was from the fiddle.. no need of version. I remove

Answer (score 1):

Long story short

```
declare @x varchar(50)='abcdefghj02002216112014'
declare @y varchar(14)=RIGHT(@x, 14)
declare @dtPart varchar(10) = CONCAT(LEFT(RIGHT(@y, 8),2), '/', substring(@y, 9,2), '/',  RIGHT(@y,4))
declare @timePart varchar(8)= concat(substring(@y,5,2), ':', substring(@y,3,2),':', left(@y,2))
declare @fullDate varchar(19) =concat(@dtPart, ' ', @timePart)
select Convert(datetime,@fullDate, 103)
```

Comment: you declared variable @x for a single value.
if I would like it to be a whole column, could i just replace the value between the quotes to a column name?

Answer (score 1):

What a horrible format!

Perhaps this will help

**Example**

```
Select ID
      ,NewValue = convert(datetime,right(S,4)+'-'+left(right(S,6),2)+'-'+left(right(S,8),2)+' '+substring(s,5,2)+':'+substring(s,3,2)+':'+substring(s,1,2))
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (right(ID,14)) ) B(s)
```

**Returns**

```
ID                        NewValue
abcdefghj02002216112014   2014-11-16 22:00:02.000
```

Comment: upvote for getting the right answer but i'll need to format millions of records.

Comment: @RogerSteinberg The (at)YourTable is just a demonstrative table variable.